# How do I cut out unsuitable habitat of a Kernel Density polygon created in RStudio and exported to ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: r, arcgis-pro

I have created KDE polygons and would like to know how to remove areas of unsuitable habitat (roads, fields, water bodies) most efficiently?

I have 'edit vertices' to remove unsuitable habitat **however** this does not change the area of the polygon I've edited? And I want to know the area of the polygon I've now reduced in size.

[image]

The light blue is the original KDE polygon and the purple is where I've cut out the unsuitable habitat - they still both have the same area attached to each polygon even though the purple has been reduced drastically in size? - vector data

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please edit your question and provide more details? Perhaps an example of what the polygons look like before and after? It would also be helpful to define what "unsuitable habitat" is for this analysis.

Comment: I think this is better? (: thanks

Comment: Are you working with vector or raster data?

Comment: It is vector data...

Comment: Have you tried using the clip or erase tools?

Comment: Thank you Aaron! The clip tool is working, I initially thought this would be a very arduous task - needing to create new polygons to remove, but it is not. Thanks for your help! Much appreciated!! (: